# WSO2 HTTPS endpoint Issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I tried to add https url at the endpoint configuration of wso2 and when i try hit the test button it showing error connecting back end but the back end is working fine. I am facing issue only with the https. http is working properly. I even tried setting this  `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>`    in axis2.xml still got the same and when i checked in the logs i am getting the following errors

**In my local System**

```
[2021-06-24 11:12:05,331]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 0ms
[2021-06-24 11:12:13,914] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while connecting to backend : https://www.google.com/, reason : peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:450)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.HostObjectUtils.sendHttpHEADRequest(HostObjectUtils.java:267)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_isURLValid(APIProviderHostObject.java:4393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:255)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:21)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_2(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:237)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:9)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**In cloud environment**

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: sample.domain.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:472)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1.doit(ControllerThreadSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$SocketTask.run(ControllerThreadSocketFactory.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ssl config of Axis2.xml

```
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
        <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
       <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
                <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="SSLVerifyClient">require</parameter>
            supports optional|require or defaults to none -->
    </transportReceiver>



  <transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
                <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <!-- ============================================== -->
        <!-- Configuration for Dynamic SSL Profile loading. -->
        <!-- Configured for 10 mins. -->
        <!-- ============================================== -->
        <parameter name="dynamicSSLProfilesConfig">
            <filePath>repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml</filePath>
            <fileReadInterval>600000</fileReadInterval>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
            <!--supports Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost or the default if none specified -->
    </transportSender>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error produced in your Local Environment is related to Peer Authentication. Generally, the `peer not authenticated` errors are populated when the trusted cert is not presented in the `client-truststore.jks` of the API Manager node. Therefore, please export the public TLS cert from your backend and add it to the `client-truststore.jks` in the API Manager server.

Regarding the second error: `Unknown Host Exception`, this is populated, when the API Manager (Java) server was not able to resolve the mentioned Hostname. Please check whether the mentioned hostname (`sample.domain.com`) is a valid one and have any DNS entries to resolve. If it is dummy, you can add a host entry in the `/etc/hosts` in your cloud environment to pick the correct IP.

Furthermore, to disable the Hostname verification in the API Manager, along with the above-mentioned configurations in the `axis2.xml`, please perform the following configurations

- Edit the `<apim>/bin/wso2server.sh`
- Add the following flag to the bottom of the script where all the JVM properties are defined

  ```sh
  -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll
  ```
- Restart the server

Comment: In the Cloud region i am able to get response through the curl command even though the hostname is not mentioned in hosts file the same when i try it adding it in wso2 endpoint and hit  i am getting `Unknown Host Exception`. is there anything i am missing

Comment: @Beson: can you do a `ping` from the Cloud environment to the mentioned hostname and share the observation. You can use the following: `ping sample.domain.com` command to check the connectivity. Also, can you update the complete stack trace that you are getting in the cloud environment?

Comment: For the firstcase i added downloaded the public certificate form chrome and added it to the `client-truststore.jks` using this command `keytool -import -alias localhost -file C:/Users/ben/Documents/google.cer -keystore C:/Users/ben/Downloads/Downloads/2.6.0/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks` still getting the same

Comment: Can you check whether that cert match with the CN that you are using or does it has the SAN values mentioning the `sample.domain.com` in it? Further, once the cert is imported to the `client-truststore.jks`, please perform a restart as well.

Comment: I am new to this and not aware of what you are asking above. I used `https://www.google.com/` as my endpoint for testing purpose and downloaded the certificate from chrome by clicking the lock icon in the url and added it to keystore with alias name as google is this even correct or please correct me

Comment: Let's sort one by one. In the Cloud Environment, are you using Google as an Endpoint in the API (production or sandbox endpoint of the API)? If yes, then what you did is correct. I believe that you have exported the certs from the Chrome and imported them using the `keytool` [1](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#step-3-importing-certificates-to-the-truststore) command to the `client-truststore.jks` of the API Manager node. Can you share whether you are running a single APIM node in the cloud?

Comment: Yes I am running single APIM node

Comment: Can you please update your question with the complete stack trace of the UnknownHostException? So that I can have a further look into it. And, is the `peer not authenticated` solved in your local environment? Further, in the cloud environment, have you configured any APIs or endpoints with `sample.domain.com`?

Comment: no in local environment still the issue persist  also i have updated the complete stack for local and cloud and also  given the ssl config in axis2.xml

Comment: Please share the following.. - Are both (local and cloud) environments are configured with any Proxy? - Perform the `ping sample.domain.com` in your cloud and verify whether it resolves the Hostname. - Have you generated a completely new `client-truststore.jks`?

Comment: No proxy has been configured. do I have to configure any ?. I have tried ping in cloud it didn't work and also I have not generated new client-truststore.jks

Comment: No, you don't have to configure any Proxy. As suspected, the `ping` command is not able to resolve the hostnames in your cloud environment. Therefore, can you try making a host entry in the `/etc/hosts` file specifying the correct IP address and the `sample.domain.com` domain name to resolve this? Please try the approach and share the observations.